# RIA Services and Inheritance in EF

Tags: entity-framework, wcf-ria-services

I have the next EF diagram:
[Image](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_AZ8yj4nlLwI/SsWq8phTbMI/AAAAAAAAADk/PgTZsYpp7Qs/EntityDesignerDiagram.jpg)

and the code service:

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
public class DomainService1 : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<db1Entities1>
{
    public IQueryable<Entity1> GetMaster1()
    {
        return this.Context.Master.OfType<Entity1>();
    }

    public IQueryable<Entity2> GetMaster2()
    {
        return this.Context.Master.OfType<Entity2>();
    }
}
```

In the compile process I have the next errors:

```
Error 1 The type 'TestInheritance.Web.Entity1' already contains a definition for '_typeId' D:\FAUst\SourceExamples\TestInheritance\TestInheritance\Generated_Code\TestInheritance.Web.g.cs 183
Error 2 The type 'TestInheritance.Web.Entity1' already contains a definition for 'TypeId' D:\FAUst\SourceExamples\TestInheritance\TestInheritance\Generated_Code\TestInheritance.Web.g.cs 273
Error 3 The type 'TestInheritance.Web.Entity2' already contains a definition for '_typeId' D:\FAUst\SourceExamples\TestInheritance\TestInheritance\Generated_Code\TestInheritance.Web.g.cs 310
Error 4 The type 'TestInheritance.Web.Entity2' already contains a definition for 'TypeId' D:\FAUst\SourceExamples\TestInheritance\TestInheritance\Generated_Code\TestInheritance.Web.g.cs 400
```

What I can doing that except this errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use inheritance like that with RIA Services. Anything you load to RIA Services that requires knowledge of the inheritance is going to fail.

Answer (score 2):

Now you can:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=RiaServices&DownloadId=8351

Comment: That link is broken, what was it refering to?