# EF Code Fist inheritance with RIA Services and Silverlight

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, wcf-ria-services, silverlight-5.0

I'm playing around with EF and RIA Services for an upcoming project. For that project, I need inheritance to be able to abstract away concrete implementations of types. Lets say we have an abstract class *CustomerBase*. Customers in the US require other data than customers in the UK, so we can implement `Customer : CustomerBase` for the UK and the US in different modules. Other modules don't have to depend on a specific implementation, because CustomerBase already covers most ground.

I built a scenario like this and my tables are created just perfectly and the RIA Service copies them to the Silverlight (v5) client. But in the Silverlight project, a statement like this ...

```
CustomerBase customer = new Customer() { /* ... */ };
```

... is invalid, because the RIA Service lets all it's entities derive from *Entity* (*CustomerBase* is shared on the main module so everyone can access it).

How would you solve this? I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508334/ria-services-and-inheritance-in-ef) thread, but the I can't find a sample that does what I need (I guess the link is broken). Is there a way to make the statement above compile or is there a workaround for this kind of problem? I can't imagine I'm the first one having this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After loads of reading and discussions in ##csharp@freenode.net, I think the best way to solve this is to create an implementation of CustomerBase on the Silverlight-Client that wraps the Customer entity generated by the RIA Services. In there I override all properties and let them access the Entitiy's fields and implement INotifyPropertyChanged on the fly.